# Display Modal Once After Login or Signup

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, modal-dialog

I have a signup/login page `index.html` and my homepage `indexHome.php`. I need to find a way to display a welcome message only once every time a user either logs in or signs up (welcome modal/welcome back modal). I think I can do it by using the form submission buttons on either the signup or login submit buttons and then pass that to the `indexHome.php`. I think another option would be to use localSession, localStorage, or cookies in my script on `indexHome.php` to do this, but I'm not really sure how. I have looked through other threads and haven't been able to find a way to do this. I have been working on the issue for a few days and am in need of some assistance. Any help is appreciated! :)

```
<div id="id05" class="modal" >
              <form class="modal-content">
                <div class="container">
                <h1><?php echo "Welcome, ".$firstname."!"?></h1>
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id05').style.display='none'" class="close2" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                  <hr>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

```
<div id="id06" class="modal" >
              <form class="modal-content">
                <div class="container">
                <h1><?php echo "Welcome back, ".$firstname."!"?></h1>
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id05').style.display='none'" class="close2" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                  <hr>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

As of right now, I have this:

```
<body onload = "welcome()">
```

```
  function welcome() {
       document.getElementById('id05').style.display='block';        
}
```

...which loads one of the modals on every refresh of the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add an event listener to your form submission buttons whenever they click 'sign up' or 'log in' that turns your modals display from none to block. Here's an example in which I will grab an element with the class form-Submit and display the welcome modal whenever they click the form submission button. I hope this helps

```
var formSubmit = document.querySelector('.form-Submit');
formSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {document.getElementById('id05').style.display='block'})
```